# XPATH selecting all preceding siblings only selects first one? Limitation of the software I'm using?

Tags: xpath

I have a simple table that I'm trying to parse data from and I'm having trouble selecting the proper elements. A representation of the table is below. The 2 TR with `class="subgroup-head"` are full width columns while all the other TR (`class="odd" or "even"`) contain 4 columns.

```
<TABLE class="transfers table">
    <TBODY>
        <TR class="subgroup-head">
            <TH>Transfers In</TH>
        <TR class="odd">
        <TR class="even">
        <TR class="odd">
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        <TR class="subgroup-head">
            <TH>Transfers Out</TH>
        <TR class="odd">
        <TR class="even">
        <TR class="odd">
        .
        .
        .
        .
```

I'm trying to select all the table rows that follow the TR with the text 'Transfers In' up until the TR with the 'Transfers Out' text. I figured I could easily do this using `preceding-sibling` and `following-sibling`. However,

`//TABLE[@class='transfers table']/TBODY[1]/TR[preceding-sibling::TR[contains(text(),'Transfers Out')]]`

only selects the first TR after the TR with class='subgroup-head' and text "Transfers Out", and

`//TABLE[@class='transfers table']/TBODY[1]/TR[following-sibling::TR[contains(text(),'Transfers Out')]]`

selects only the TR with class='subgroup-head' and text "Transfers In". I had assumed both would select all rows before or after the TR with 'Transfers Out' text. Is this an issue with the software I'm using?

Note: The software I'm using doesn't support `preceding` or `following` alone, only with -sibling.

I tried a variant xpath with a count method, but it also delivers the same results
`//TABLE[@class='transfers table']/TBODY[1]/TR[count(preceding-sibling::TR[contains(text(),'Transfers Out')])=1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the function call `contains(text(),'Transfers Out')`. `text()` returns a node set containing all the text node children of the `subgroup-head` node. This is converted to a string for use in `contains`, which means the value of the *first* node in the set is used. In this case that is the whitespace-only node before the  element, which doesn’t match.

If you use the current context element instead (i.e. `.`), it will work. The string value of an element is the concatenation of the string values of all its descendent text nodes, which is what you want.

The two queries you want are therefore:

```
//TABLE[@class='transfers table']/TBODY[1]/TR[preceding-sibling::TR[contains(.,'Transfers Out')]]
```

and

```
//TABLE[@class='transfers table']/TBODY[1]/TR[following-sibling::TR[contains(.,'Transfers Out')]]
```

(this second one will also include the leading `Transfers In` row that you might want to filter out).

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer and the 2 xpaths for selecting the 2 separate groups of elements I wanted were

`//TABLE[@class='transfers table']/TBODY[1]/TR[@class='odd' or @class='even'][following-sibling::TR[contains(text(),'Transfers out')]]`

and

`//TABLE[@class='transfers table']/TBODY[1]/TR[@class='odd' or @class='even'][preceding-sibling::TR[contains(text(),'Transfers out')]]`